# NDIS driver installation failed while installing e303c Huawei modem in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: networking, 13.04, usb-modem

Installation of the driver for the Huawei modem fails with the following error:

> Error:Install NDIS driver failed.The Compiling environment is not all
>   ready. Please check gcc,make and kernel build to be all installed.

Please answer in non technical terms,I'm new to Linux (don't even know commands properly).

Comment: Could you clarify how are you installing the driver? Did you use a tutorial?

Comment: Do you even need the NDIS driver, I don't think so, nut have not looked into this? What are you doing that gives that error message? If you are met that technically skilled, how come you even get that message, any tutorial you tries that fails when you follow it?

Comment: see the post for NDIS driver installation problem,http://askubuntu.com/questions/323031/how-to-install-ndis-driver-for-huawei-mobile-broadband-devices/368669#368669