# How to Install NDIS Driver for Huawei mobile broadband devices?

Tags: software-installation, ndiswrapper

My 3G dongal requires the [proprietary driver](http://www.mediafire.com/download/9oa5g9dx5xeoy97/mp21.zip) to properly work with Ubuntu.
It comes along with Huawei Mobile Partner installer. I was able to install Huawei Mobile Partner and the corresponding driver in **Ubuntu Linux 10.04** without an any problem.

However, I can't install it in **Ubuntu 13.10. (Didn't work since 12.04)**
It gives the below error.
I've tried installing build-essential.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

> "make: *** [install] Error 2
>   Install NDIS driver failed.
>   The compiling environment is not all ready.
>   Please check gcc, make and kernel build(/lib/modules/3.8.0-26-generic/build) to be all installed?
>   Now please enter any key to finish other installations.
>   NDIS is disabled, and only Modem can be used".
>   These packages gcc, make, and others are installed.

**(The output is taken from a previous version of Ubuntu. The same error message is generated in 13.10. You can regenerate this error by trying to install my [driver package](http://www.mediafire.com/download/9oa5g9dx5xeoy97/mp21.zip). The mobile broadband is not required for the installation)**

Comment: Please include the actual error message (scroll a bit up interminal). Also, for future questions, please copy&paste output from terminal instead of making screenshots.

Comment: Install NDIS driver failed.
The compiling environment is not all ready.
Please check gcc, make and kernel buid(/lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build) to be all installed?
Now please enter any key to finish other installations.

NDIS is disabled, and only Modem can be used.
USBSERIAL_TARGET_PATH = 
ACM_TARGET_PATH =

Comment: Actually, I meant the lines above "make: *** [modules] Error 2". The actual error is very probably printed somewhere above.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/330967/151875
has one answer, which might be helpful.

Comment: 0k! The answer is good for Ubuntu 13.10 too. But there is also a new problem: when I try (with Movistart Partner 21) to connect to an element of the list, I get only a **retry to connect**. I am in Italy... Any solution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Solution for NDIS Driver failed to install problem on HUAWEI Broadband devices:

- Run the below command after installing the `Huawei Modem Driver` with **NDIS driver install failed**.

  ```
    sudo gedit /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c
  ```

[image]

- Locate to the line `Ln 2718`,change `dbg ("cant't kmalloc dev");` to `//dbg ("cant't kmalloc dev");`(*adding double `//` infront of dbg*),save the file and close the *terminal*.
- Open new terminal and Change the directory path to `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver` by running the below command

  ```
    cd /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver
  ```
- Reinstall the driver by running the below command

  ```
    sudo ./install
  ```
- Now,it shows **NDIS driver installed successfully**.

[image]

Comment: How did you know it!!! hahaha I really appreciate your help man!

Comment: or it may be at the line 2590.

Comment: you are super cool dude

Comment: @AvinashRaj But I am not able to connect to internet.. When I plugin my datacard.. Could you help me. I am terribly frustrated..

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Get into [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company) if you want to talk.

Comment: @avi I am into the chat.. Could you come there ? I joked with you... :-) As I am not able to connect to the internet, I am not able to read my subjects...

Comment: @ArupRakshit it's working flawlessly.

Comment: Doesn't work with an error (on Debnian 8 KDE_64Bit) `$ /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/MobilePartner.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libcore.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` I think, it doesn't work only on 64-Bit OS

Comment: Or: `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/MobilePartner.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libfreetype.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64` After using this: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"`

Answer (score 3):

#### Another method:

Run the below script only after `Install NDIS driver failed` error

```
#!/bin/bash 
# check if the driver was installed or not
path="/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver"
if [ "$(ls -A $path)" ]; then
     tput setaf 6; echo "Huawei modem drivers for linux are already installed on your pc.Please wait for NDIS driver installation."; tput sgr0
     perl -i  -pe 's#^(\s*dbg \("can.t kmalloc dev"\);)#//$1#' /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c
     cd $path
     sudo ./install
else

    tput setaf 1; echo "Huawei modem drivers for linux are not installed on your pc.Please install that."; tput sgr0
fi
```

- Create a script named **ndis.sh** with the above code and save it to your `Home` directory.
- Run the below command to give execute permission for the created script.

  ```
  cd /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/script
  sudo chmod +x ndis.sh
  ```
- Run the `ndis.sh` script,

  ```
  bash ndis.sh
  ```

That's all.I created this script because in the above [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/368669/202806),i mentioned to locate to the line 2718 and add `//` infront of it.But in some cases the code `dbg ("cant't kmalloc dev");` was not on the line 2718,so it was so hard to find the line of code manually and then add `//` infront of that.

This script automatically search for the line which contains the code `dbg ("cant't kmalloc dev");` and put `//` infront of it.So that the line of code changes to comment,and then make the NDIS driver to install successfully.