# problem installing mobile partner driver

Tags: drivers, mobile-broadband, huawei, ndiswrapper

While installing Mobile partner I got error saying NDIS driver failed so because of that I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323031/how-to-install-ndis-driver-for-huawei-mobile-broadband-devices) link and according to that I changed my hw_cdc_driver.c file and while installing driver I'm getting error what is the solution for this problem

```
<cp: cannot stat ‘/driver/64bit/HWActivator’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘/driver/HWActivator’: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /driver/10-Huawei-Datacard.rules: No such file or directory
./install: line 48: /driver/ndis_driver/ndis_install: No such file or directory
./install: line 50: /driver/patch/patch_install: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/driver/HuaweiAutoStart.desktop’: No such file or directory 
./install: line 64: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
./install: line 89: /driver/skeleton.bak: No such file or directory
./install: line 91: /driver/runhwactivator: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/driver/runhwactivator’: No such file or directory
./install: line 109: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc5.d
‘/etc/rc5.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc5.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
./install: line 125: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
./install: line 126: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc3.d
‘/etc/rc3.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc3.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
./install: line 125: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
./install: line 126: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc2.d
‘/etc/rc2.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc2.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
./install: line 125: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
./install: line 126: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc4.d
‘/etc/rc4.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc4.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
./install: line 125: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
./install: line 126: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
./install: line 137: /driver/sleep-settings.sh: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/driver/usbmod’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/driver/startMobilePartner’: No such file or directory
./install: line 145: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
./install: line 146: /driver/Uninstall: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The above error was because of you renamed the driver folder into something else.Don't change the name of the folder.The folder name must be **driver** otherwise it shows the error like above.

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~/Desktop/driver$ ls
10-Huawei-Datacard-old.rules  HuaweiAutoStart.desktop  sleepsettings
10-Huawei-Datacard.rules      install                  sleep-settings.sh
32bit                         Mandriva2011_Patch       startMobilePartner
49huawei                      ndis_driver              Uninstall
60-cdrom_id.rules             patch                    usbmod
64bit                         ReadMe
copying                       skeleton
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~/Desktop/driver$
```

Comment: i haven't renamed any folder .. this is the path which i have given     while installing       cd /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver

Comment: delete all the folders inside `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner` directory and then try to install the original drivers first.

Comment: your driver directory looks like mine?

Comment: i did wat u told i'm still getting problem

Comment: except  Mandriva2011_Patch  i have all in my folder does that make any difference ?

Comment: start from first,1.extract the driver 2.Install the driver by running `sudo ./install` 3.Now there appears driver folder inside `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner`.It will be installed as ndis driver installation failed.Please try it and let me know.After that i will tell you the next steps.

Comment: Ya I did the same thing now I'm getting error as NDIS driver failed. wat must be the exact problem

Comment: yes,now run this command and post it's output `ls /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver`.

Comment: 10-Huawei-Datacard-old.rules  HWActivator     skeleton
10-Huawei-Datacard.rules      install         sleepsettings
32bit                         ndis_driver     sleep-settings.sh
64bit                         patch           startMobilePartner
copying                       ReadMe          Uninstall
HuaweiAutoStart.desktop       runhwactivator  usbmod

Comment: this is wat i get ..